# Python 3.4 and AVRO: Unable to convert the simple message in AVRO, based on schema?

Tags: python, python-3.x, avro

I am looking to create a avro message for each record (csv) with metadata header i.e. with nested schema.

I am using Python 3.4. I have the required modules i.e. avro-python3 downloaded.
I have the record data in form of csv with its header.

Basically I have the code for creating required message and metadata header.

My AVSC file (Sample only):

```
Schema: {"name": "person","type": "record","fields": [{"name": "address","type": {"type" : "record","name" : "AddressUSRecord","fields" : [{"name": "streetaddress", "type": "string"},{"name": "city", "type":"string"},{"name": "pin", "type":"long"}]}}]}
```

My record is also created. (Showing the pretty format of record).

For pin: 123.456 (float value)

However, when I am trying to convert the above record in avro format, based on avsc file mentioned, it fails saying the "Tha datum is not the example of schema".

Code:

```
import avro.schema
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter
from avro.io import DatumReader, DatumWriter
import csv
import json
# header class to give header data. Just simple assignment
from header import Header
# body class to give body, just simple assignment for now.
from pnlData import PnlData
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    schemaFile = "/path/tardisPnl.avsc"
    outFile = "/path/SampleOutLanding.avro"
    schema = avro.schema.Parse(open(schemaFile, "r").read())

    a = Header()
    a.generateMessageId() #Simple text generated for now
    a.generateTimestamp() #Simple number generated for now
    #print(a.__dict__)
    b = PnlData()
    b.generatePnlData() #Simple value assigned as seen in example
    #print(b.__dict__)

    landingMessage = {}
    landingMessage["header"] = a.__dict__
    landingMessage["pnlData"] = b.__dict__

    #print (json.dumps(landingMessage))

    writer = DataFileWriter(open(outFile, "wb"), DatumWriter(), schema)
    try:
        writer.append(landingMessage)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error: %s ' % (e))

    writer.close()
```

I have tried to convert the above avro schema to JSON schema, then created sample JSON data based on the schema (online links), to see if my data object is correct. Infact I created my record based on sample data generated based on the schema.

However, when I try to use them and run the code it always fails.

I am not much familiar with AVRO, so need to understand what I am missing here? Why this simple data and schema is not working?

---

I first tried the following simple records (same sample online tool) and schema, and it works.

Simple avsc:

```
{"name": "person","type": "record","fields": [{"name": "firstname", "type": "string"},{"name": "lastname", "type": "string"},{"name": "address","type": {"type" : "record","name" : "AddressUSRecord","fields" : [{"name": "streetaddress", "type": "string"},{"name": "city", "type":"string"}]}}]}
```

Simple Data (Again pretty printed):

```
{
  "firstname": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN",
  "lastname": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZAB",
  "address": {
    "streetaddress": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN",
    "city": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO"
  }
}
```

If I create the above dict, and pass the same (same code, not changes) to avsc file as above, it works fine.

Only difference in my avsc and (simple) sample avsc is one extra nested attribute, etc. I am unable to find the reason for not working in my slightly complex data.

Answer (score 1):

The `fastavro` library has a `validate` function that can help with this.

Using the data and schema you provided, it would look like this:

```
schema = {
   "type":"record",
   "name":"SomeName",
   "doc":"This schema contains the metadata fields wrapped in a header field which follows the official SA MessageHeader schema.",
   "fields":[
      {
         "name":"header",
         "type":{
            "type":"record",
            "name":"MessageHeader",
            "fields":[
               {
                  "name":"messageId",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"businessId",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"batchId",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"sourceSystem",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"secondarySourceSystem",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"sourceSystemCreationTimestamp",
                  "type":"long"
               },
               {
                  "name":"sentBy",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"sentTo",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"messageType",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"schemaVersion",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"processing",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"sourceLocation",
                  "type":"string"
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "name":"pnlData",
         "type":{
            "type":"record",
            "name":"pnlDataDetails",
            "fields":[
               {
                  "name":"granularity",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"pnl_type",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"pnl_subtype",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"date",
                  "type":"int"
               },
               {
                  "name":"book",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"currency",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"category",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"subcategory",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"riskcategory",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"market_name",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"risk_order",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"tenor",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"product",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"trade_id",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"pnl_local",
                  "type":"long"
               },
               {
                  "name":"pnl_cde",
                  "type":"long"
               },
               {
                  "name":"pnl_status",
                  "type":"string"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}

record = {
    "pnlData": {
        "pnl_cde": 997.8100000024,
        "pnl_status": "locked",
        "granularity": "detailed view",
        "book": "8271",
        "date": 20181130,
        "subcategory": "None",
        "pnl_local": 997.7899999917,
        "pnl_subtype": "Regular",
        "tenor": "None",
        "pnl_type": "Daily",
        "risk_order": "None",
        "market_name": "None",
        "trade_id": "None",
        "category": "None",
        "product": "None",
        "currency": "cad",
        "riskcategory": "None"
    },
    "header": {
        "sentBy": "SYSTEM",
        "businessId": "T1",
        "messageId": "pnl_0001",
        "processing": "RealTime",
        "messageType": "None",
        "sourceLocation": "None",
        "sentTo": "SA",
        "secondarySourceSystem": "None",
        "schemaVersion": "1.6T",
        "sourceSystem": "SYSTEM",
        "sourceSystemCreationTimestamp": 1236472051,
        "batchId": "None"
    }
}

import fastavro

fastavro.validation.validate(record, schema)
```

The error I get is the following: `"SomeName.pnlData.pnlDataDetails.pnl_local is <997.7899999917> of type <class 'float'> expected long"`

Comment: Thanks @Scott for pointing the issue.
Please note that I have edited the schemato remove the confidnetial data (missed earlier).
Got to know about the issue of long vs float. Thanks.